# what will happen if my cpu usuage stays 100% for 30 mins or so on linux server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, cpu-usage

I have Amazon Ec2 small instance with 1.7Gb RAM. I have 3 websites running on them.
I have the scripts which does the `web crawling` every day and perform some caluclation.

I have not deployed them yet. But i want to know that if those scripts run for 30 mins and processor usage is 100% what will happen to websites. Will they stop working, or be slow?

I am not sure.

Sites are not high traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt you will experience ill effects with low traffic, but you could quite easily run tests on the speed and such.

Comment: do u know how much visit per day i need to have in order to cause issue. i am not able to get that idea

Comment: I couldn't tell you, but like i said, it's trivial to run a test to find your limits

Comment: sorry for that but i don't know what to test , how to test and which perforface is good or bad.

Comment: Create a large file on the web server, then as you're downloading it start the cpu heavy program and watch for performance changes in the download. You could also test max. requests per hour by downloading the front page over and over for that period of time.